# Serve file from cache folder if it exists, otherwise rewrite to "index.php" using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server

Suppose in root directory I have **one file** (called `index.php`) and **one folder** (called `caches`).
I want that if the file exist in caches folder serve that file (`caches/xxx.html`) otherwise request send to `index.php`.

For example I will send request to server: `https://example.com/how-to-do`
and Apache search first in `cache/`. If `how-to-do.html` exists then send (rewrite Apache) `how-to-do.html` otherwise send request to `index.php`.

This my `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you only dealing with requests for the document root, or would `/foo/bar/how-to-do` also be a valid request?

Comment: thanks,for fix problem (nested folder) i change your code from `^[^/.]+$ cache/$0.html ` to `(.*) cache/$0.html` in your opinion is this problem ?

Comment: If you are using the `$0` backreference then you don't need to surround the pattern in parentheses. (By surrounding the pattern in parentheses you are creating a `$1` backreference.) However, the regex `.*` is rather too general and inefficient here. Regex should be as specific as possible. The regex `.*` also matches the target URL (ie. `cache/<file>.html`) so results in an additional (unnecessary) filesystem check. If your URLs don't contain dots then use `^[^.]+$` instead to match multiple path depths (simply removing the slash from character class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediately before your last rule (ie. before the `# Send Requests To Front Controller...` comment) you can add something like the following:

```
# Check if cache file exists and serve from cache if it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$0.html -f
RewriteRule ^[^/.]+$ cache/$0.html [L]
```

This only checks for requests that target the document root, eg. `/how-to-do` - as in your example. It also assumes that your URL-path does not contain a dot (used to delimit file extensions). It does not target requests with multiple path segments, eg. `/foo/bar`.

To match multiple path segments then simply remove the slash from the regex character class. ie. `^[^.]+$`.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^[^/.]+$` matches any non-empty URL-path that does not contain the characters *slash* and *dot*. In other words it matches URL-paths that consist of a single path segment, excluding files (that naturally include a dot before the file extension). In `.htaccess`, the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does *not* start with a slash.

`$0` is a backreference that contains the entire URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. `^[^/.]+$`).

---

#### Reference

The official Apache docs should be your go to reference for this (although the docs are rather concise and somewhat lacking examples in places):

- [Apache mod-rewrite Contents](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/)
- **[Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)**
- [Apache mod_rewrite Reference](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

  - [`RewriteRule` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)
  - [`RewriteCond` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Comment: It works exactly and I think $0 does the main work
Can you tell me the source of your training in this field?
I have been studying regex and .htaccess for almost two weeks and I could not solve it!

Comment: @Mahdighhastam I've updated my answer with more explanation and some reference links. The Apache docs are my go-to reference (although not to everyone's taste it would seem). The [mod_rewrite introduction](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html) is a good place to start. It is good to question everything and not to copy/paste `.htaccess` without understanding what they do. Best of luck :)