# Serve cache via apache/htaccess, if file exists, otherwise load data from database

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I found this question:

- [Serve file from cache folder if it exists, otherwise rewrite to "index.php" using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71485573/serve-file-from-cache-folder-if-it-exists-otherwise-rewrite-to-index-php-usin)

and it was useful but i'm not able to write code for my system.

This is my URL structure:

```
www.example.com/typeOfPost/category/ID/permalink
```

(For example: `www.example.com/news/sport/8734/here-goes-article-title`)

My cache structure is this:

```
ROOT/cache/responsive/ID/typeOfPost/category/permalink
```

where `permalink` is a file without extension that contains the html code of the page.

Unfortunately for cache file I can't use the same URL structure so I don't know how to check if cache file exists and if so load it, otherwise load data from database.

At the moment I'm reading checking for cache file via PHP and if it exists I load it otherwise I load data from database.

For server performance I'd like to to bypass PHP and check for cache file via Apache, I think this is the right approach... isn't it? If so, how can I write the `.htaccess` file?

This is the code i wrote but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/responsive/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)$ /cache/responsive/$3/$1/$2/$4 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/responsive/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) -f
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)$ /cache/responsive/$3/$1/$2/$4 [L]
> ```

The preceding *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) should be checking for the existence of the same file that you are wanting to rewrite the request to in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string. As in the question/example you linked to, which is checking for the existence of `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$0.html` before ultimately rewriting the request to `cache/$0.html` - as you can see, they are the same. In your code, they clearly are not. Otherwise, everything else about your rule would seem to be OK.

So, your rule should be written like this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/responsive/$3/$1/$2/$4 -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)$ /cache/responsive/$3/$1/$2/$4 [L]
```

The `RewriteRule` directive first matches against the requested URL. If it matches then the preceding *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) checks that the "cache" file exists. If the preceding *condition* is successful then the `RewriteRule` directive performs the *substitution* as stated.

However, the slash prefix on the *substitution* is unnecessary and should be omitted, so that it rewrites to a filesystem path, as a opposed to a URL-path (which triggers mod_rewrite to remap the request to the filesystem). Although the net result is the same in this instance.

You also don't need to capture the first two path segments separately, as these remain as a pair in the cache file path.

For example, it could be written like this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/responsive/$2/$1/$3 -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[^/]+)/(\d+)/([^/]+)$ cache/responsive/$2/$1/$3 [L]
```

`\d` is a shorthand character class that represents *digits* and is the same as `[0-9]`

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly! Now i just noticed that this caching approach opens another question: at the moment cache is served via php so i can check if admin is logged (via php session variable) and in that case serve the db version otherwhise serve the cached file.

With htaccess approach cached file is always served both if i'm logged or not.

i found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342509/get-php-session-vars-in-htaccess and the workaround 2 could be a solution but it is not reccomended... can i ask you what you think about that?